# How to check traffic and connected devices?

Tags: wifi, monitoring

Recently, I setup my Pi 3 to work as Wi-Fi access point through the Tor network.
Is there any way to check what devices are connected and how much traffic is sent through the Pi by individual devices? Some sort of admin area like routers have?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ipfm` command line tool, a very good tool for your requirements.

For more information, see [man(8) ipfm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ipfm.8.html).

**Sample output:**

```
# IPFMv0.11.5 2017/07/24 10:12:08 -- dump every 0d00:00:01 -- listening on wlan0
# Host                                  In (bytes)    Out (bytes)  Total (bytes)
192.168.42.2                              55817571        2455117       58272688

192.168.42.9                               3744360       13292442       17036802

192.168.42.10                             11939640         818201       12757841

192.168.42.12                              5223082        1141022        6364104

192.168.42.1                                     0           3096           3096
```